# Radial distribution function

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, chemistry

I have tried to rewrite my old IDL code to calculate the radial correlation function for a regular 2D crystal structure.

The theory behind this function is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function

**Update 1:**

> The radial density distribution counts the number of points in a
>   distance between $r$ and $r +\Delta r$ from each considered central
>   point (below one marked as red). The area of such a *"shell"* is $2\pi
> r \Delta r$. The density distributions are averaged for all center
>   points and then normalized by the total point density times the ring
>   area for each radius.

[image]

**Update 2:**

> It is important that the maximum radius (the maximum shell) for each
>   center point does not cross the edges of the available point
>   coordiantes (corresponding to the range defined by the smallest and
>   largest x and y point value). That means that a point close to the
>   edges has a maller maximum radius (smallest distance to the next
>   edge) than a center point (for a square: maximum radius = half of the
>   diagonal).

My question: **is it possible to improve my "unreadable" and slow code, which does not use any special mathematica functions?**.

Also I must have made a normalization error, since the function does not converge at g(r)=1 (see plot below).

As input I have taken a crystal image recorded with a high resolution camera:

[image]

[Dr. belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/dr-belisarius) has detected all coordinates by the following one-liner:

```
pts = ComponentMeasurements[Binarize@ImageSubtract
   [image, BilateralFilter[image, 4, 1]], "Centroid"];
```

These points `pts` I have used to determine the radial correlation function.

The resulting plot is:

[image]

The full code is given here:

```
Clear[radialDensityDistribution];
radialDensityDistribution [listData_, mrr_: 0, mrc_: dDiag, 
  subdivision_: 50] :=
 (
  (*listData: list of 2D data points*)
  (*mrr: distance from edge*)
  (*mrc: calculation radius from central point*)
  (*subdivision: number of in size's from mean point distance*)

  n = Length[listData];

  x = listData[[All, 1]];
  y = listData[[All, 2]];

  minCorner = {Min[x], Min[y]};
  maxCorner = {Max[x], Max[y]};

  diag = maxCorner - minCorner;
  dDiag = Sqrt[diag.diag];

  area = diag[[1]]*diag[[2]];

  pointDensity = n/area;

  deltaR = (area/n)^(1.0/2);
  dr = deltaR/subdivision;

  maxShell = Floor[mrc/dr];

  g = Array[0 &, maxShell];
  centralPoint = Array[0 &, n];

  com = {Mean[x], Mean[y]};
  radii = Sqrt[(x - com[[1]])^2 + (y - com[[2]])^2];
  maxrad = Max[radii] // N;

  centralIndex = Flatten@Position[radii + mrr, n_ /; n <= maxrad];
  nCentral = Length[centralIndex];

  p = {x[[centralIndex]], y[[centralIndex]]};

  g = 0;

  Table[
   dist = {p[[1, 2 ;; All]] - p[[1, i]], 
      p[[2, 2 ;; All]] - p[[2, i]]}[[All, i ;; All]];
   shell = 
    Floor[Sqrt[
       dist[[1, All]]*dist[[1, All]] + dist[[2, All]]*dist[[2, All]]]/
      dr];
   h = HistogramList[shell, {0, maxShell - 1, 1}][[2, All]];
   g = h + g,
   {i, 1, nCentral - 1}
   ];

  Table[
   areaShell = Pi*(((shell + 1.0)*dr)^2 - (shell*dr)^2);
   g[[shell]] = g[[shell]]/(1.0*nCentral*areaShell*pointDensity),
   {shell, 1, maxShell - 1}
   ];

  rn = (Range[maxShell - 1] - 0.5)*dr;
  {g, rn, deltaR}
  )

image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/czhuI.png"];

pts = ComponentMeasurements[
    Binarize@ImageSubtract[image, BilateralFilter[image, 4, 1]], 
    "Centroid"][[All, 2]];

extx = Max[pts[[All, 1]]] - Min[pts[[All, 1]]];
exty = Max[pts[[All, 2]]] - Min[pts[[All, 2]]];
ext = Min[extx, exty];

{g, rn, deltaR} = radialDensityDistribution [pts, ext/4, ext/4, 20];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{rn, g}], PlotRange -> Full, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"g(r)", ""}, {"r (pixels)", ""}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: Could you please explain **in words** what do you do with the points in the shell in `{r , r+dr}`

Comment: @Dr. belisarius, Thank you for your comment ... I added some more information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I will show a simple and fast approach to computing the pair correlation function (radial distribution function) for a 2D system of point particles.:

```
radialDistributionFunction2D[pts_?MatrixQ, boxLength_Real, nBins_: 350] :=
 Module[{gr, r, binWidth = boxLength/(2 nBins), npts = Length@pts, rho},
  rho = npts/boxLength^2; (* area number density *)
  {r, gr} = HistogramList[(*compute and bin the distances between points of interest*)
             Flatten @ DistanceMatrix @ pts, {0.005, boxLength/4., binWidth}];
  r = MovingMedian[r, 2]; (* take center of each bin as r *)
  gr = gr/(2 Pi r rho binWidth npts); (* normaliza g(r) *)
  Transpose[{r, gr}] (* combine r and g(r) *)
 ]
```

Here is how you use it:

```
rdf = radialDistributionFunction2D[pts, 1023.];
ListLinePlot[rdf, PlotRange ->{{0, 150}, All}, Mesh -> 80]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that you get the correct normalization for free. This took about `1.2` seconds on my machine. I have restricted the plot range to show the interesting features.

Comment: Isn't this affected by a bias coming from the points near the border? (not sure, I'm just asking)

Comment: @Dr.belisarius. For small systems, that may be an issue. But this crystal structure has about 6000 atoms. Also the normalization and the fact that we bin a quarter of the box takes care of any edge effect that may be present.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that you're binning only a quarter of the box. Mostly because I'm on v9 and can't run the snippet without modifying it first

Comment: @Dr.belisarius. Sorry, I meant I was binning distances that fall within a quarter of the box length not just binning a quarter of the points. Usually for molecular dynamics simulation where one bin distances for different time periods half the box length is the standard max `r` to consider. I chose a quarter of the box length since the local density dies out way before that distance.

Comment: oh, OK. Understood now. Thanks again

Comment: @Dr.belisarius. You're welcome. I also want to mention that the only v10 function here is `DistanceMatrix`. But there's a function ``HierarchicalClustering`DistanceMatrix `` in v9 that does the same thing. But I think `EuclideanDistance` is not the default distance function, so you'll have to specify that.

Comment: I am voting for your excellent mathematica-like solution. I have the feeling that it is easily adaptable also to 3D systems ? When you have time: `please see the Update 2 remark`. Is that considered in your caclulation? I am using ver. 10.4.

Comment: @mrz. You're right it is easily adaptable to 3D systems, all you have to do is change the normalization from `2 Pi r dr` to `4 Pi r^2 dr` and of course use volume density instead of area density. With regards to your update see my comment to @Dr.belisarius above.

Comment: May I ask you (since you are probably a Physicist) if you have ever worked also with the `"bond correlation function"?` (sometimes reffered as g6(r)). See also page 34 from https://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/12327/1/Knapek_Christina.pdf

Comment: @mrz. Not a physicist but a physical chemist, yeah I know a fair bit about correlation functions. If you ask a question, I will try to answer it.

Comment: How would you modify your code when you want to consider all points as center points. The maximum radius of each point is depending on its distance to the next edge. That would improve the statistics for the small distances (less than a quarter of the whole box). This would be very helpful.

Comment: @mrz Unless there's another reason you need to compute the `g(r)` this way, which would mean re-writing the whole code since you won't be able to use `DistanceMatrix` as I've used here, I think the `g(r)` already looks good.

Comment: @mrz, The best way to do what you want is probably to make your system periodic and use the minimum image boundary condition for computing distances.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius is still correct, it's affected by particles at the border no matter how far out you compute (as there are artificially empty volumes of concentric shells sticking "out of the image" for point near the border); this is why the RDF dips below 1.0 at long distances computed here, where it's supposed to compute to exactly 1.0 at long distances for uncorrelated systems.  You need to account for periodicity.  I'm working on a WFR contribution that does this.

Answer (score 8):

"Disclaimer": This is solely an attempt to clean/speed up OP's code as it was presented, as I have not tried to figure out an alternative algorithm to do the calculation.

First a few comments:

- You might want to localize all the intermediate variables you use in a `Block`.
- When the deepest indice(s) in `Part` is `All`, we don't need to specify them. That is, `p[[All,2,All,All]]` is simply equivalent to `p[[All,2]]`.
- `Table` is not a looping construct per se: `Table` produces a **table of values**, so unless we do something with the result (e.g. `tab = Table[...]`), we should use something else. In OP's case, they could be replaced with `Do`, but as we will see, we can do away with them entirely.

The bottleneck seems to be the calls to `HistogramList`, which happens `nCentral` times, 4397 in the example. There are two things we can do with this part of the code: turn the procedural `g=0;Do[...;g=g+h]` into a functional equivalent using `Fold`, and replacing `HistogramList` with a home-cooked, faster variant. We look at the last point first.

The bin specification `{0, maxShell - 1, 1}` gives unit bins $[0,1)$, $[1,2)$, etc., and since `shell` has integer values, `HistogramList` just tallies the values in `shell` that are less than `maxShell - 1`. Thus we can

1. Pick the `shell` values that are less than `maxShell - 1`
2. `Tally` a `Sort`ed version of the result
3. Turn it into a `SparseArray` with default element 0 and correct length

Here is the code:

```
histList[shell_, maxShell_] :=
SparseArray[
  Rule @@ Transpose[Tally[1 +
    Sort[Pick[shell, Negative[shell - maxShell + 1]]]
  ]]
, maxShell - 1]
```

The `g=0;Do[...;g=g+h]` part can now be made functional using

```
gAcc[g_, i_] := Block[{dist, shell},
  dist = {p[[1, i + 1 ;; All]] - p[[1, i]], p[[2, i + 1 ;; All]] - p[[2, i]]};
  shell = Floor[Sqrt[dist[[1]]^2 + dist[[2]]^2]/dr];
  g + histList[shell, maxShell]
]
```

and finally

```
g = Fold[gAcc, 0, Range[nCentral - 1]];
```

On my machine this is about 4 times faster than OP's code.

Finally, the last part that modifies `g` can be vectorized, so no loop is necessary. Simply:

```
shells = Range[maxShell - 1];
areaShells = Pi*(((shells + 1.0)*dr)^2 - (shells*dr)^2);
g = g/(nCentral*areaShells*pointDensity);
```

Comment: Thank you vey much for your help ... your explanations are great ...

Answer (score 8):

```
image = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/czhuI.png"; 
pts = ComponentMeasurements[Binarize@ImageSubtract[image, BilateralFilter[image, 4, 1]], 
                           "Centroid"][[All, 2]];

lpts = Length@pts;

(* the following is slow and not  really needed, we could take the center 
   to be at ImageDimensions/2 *)

nm = NMinimize[Tr[#.# & /@  Thread[Subtract[pts, {x0 + Cos[ArcTan[-y0 + #[[2]],
            -x0 + #[[1]]]], y0 + Sin[ArcTan[-y0 + #[[2]], -x0 + #[[1]]]]} & /@ 
                                     pts]]], {{x0, 400, 600}, {y0, 400, 600}}]

(*center*)
(*{9.29992*10^8, {x0 -> 504.879, y0 -> 505.181}}*)

ctr = {x0, y0} /. nm[[2]]
centeredPts = Subtract[#, ctr] & /@ pts;
xyLimits = Transpose[{-1/2 #, 1/2 #} &@ctr];
ptsInZone = Select[pts, xyLimits[[1, 1]] < #[[1]] < xyLimits[[1, 2]] &&
                        xyLimits[[2, 1]] < #[[2]] < xyLimits[[2, 2]] &];

f = Nearest[pts];

g[pt_, rad_] := Rest@f[pt, {lpts, rad}]
ran[n_] := Range[n, 250, n]
ptsAtAllRanges[pt_, n_] := g[pt, #] & /@ ran[n]

scale = 2;
pp = Differences[Length /@ ptsAtAllRanges[#, scale]] & /@ ptsInZone;
ListLinePlot[(Mean /@ Transpose@pp)/Rest@ran[scale], PlotRange -> All]
```

The horizontal scale is divided by `2`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your `g(r)` is not normalized to `1`.

Comment: @RunnyKine I didn't (and don't) understand the full requirements.

Comment: @RunnyKine But in any case it seems  just a multiplication factor for all the set

Comment: Yes, I wonder where that factor got lost.

Comment: This is again a wonderful code ... the curve profile is correct. I am sure it will take me one week to roughly understand it ;-). Concerning the normalization: see here http://www.physics.emory.edu/faculty/weeks//idl/gofr2.html