# average distance between features on image

Tags: image-processing

I have this image:

[image]

and I would like to measure the average distance between the red dots.
It is important to know that they are distributed in 3D and we are looking through a slice 50nm thick (in other words, we are look at a projections of the 3D sample).

First attempt: I implemented the algorithm (for objects distributed in 2D) in the post: [Radial distribution function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110743/radial-distribution-function)

```
pts = ComponentMeasurements[Binarize@ImageSubtract[image, BilateralFilter[image, 4, 1]],     "Centroid"][[All, 2]];
radialDistributionFunction2D[pts_?MatrixQ, boxLength_Real,nBins_: 500] := Module[{gr, r, binWidth = boxLength/(2 nBins), npts = Length@pts,rho}, rho = npts/boxLength^2;(*area number density*){r, gr} =   HistogramList[(*compute and bin the distances between points of \interest*)Flatten@DistanceMatrix@pts,{0.005, boxLength/4., binWidth}];
r = MovingMedian[r, 2];(*take center of each bin as r*)gr = gr/(2 Pi r rho binWidth npts);(*normaliza g(r)*)Transpose[{r, gr}] (*combine r and g(r)*)]

rdf = radialDistributionFunction2D[pts, 1024];
ListLinePlot[rdf, PlotRange -> {All, All}, Mesh -> 100]
```

and it gives:

[image]

How to interpret these results (2D vs 3D)? How do I make use of the scale bar in the microscopy image?

Comment: "How to interpret these results (2D vs 3D)? How do I make use of the scale bar in the microscopy image?" The fact that you want to accomplish this using Mathematica does not make these "Mathematica questions", I'm afraid. You will have to first figure out how to do that from first principles, given the context of your experiment. I also worry that the 3D info is no longer present in the image, unless it is encoded in the brightness somehow.

Comment: the 3D information is indeed no longer in the image. One could assume random 3D distribution of the red features.